# Old urls are still working after implementing friendly_id on rails app. How can I stop them and redirect to 404?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I implemented `friendly_id` on my rails app. Earlier when clicked on a link the url used to look like below:

`https://example.com/search?category_id=228`

After implementing `friendly_id` when the link was clicked it started to give url as follows:

```
https://example.com/search?category_id=construction-and-heavy-equipment
```

I have a `404` method implemented on the platform. When given invalid urls it redirects to `404` error page. It works fine for invalid urls.

But now when I tested giving the old url i.e `https://example.com/search?category_id=228` it is still working. How can I stop this?

**controller**

```
  def search_equipments
    begin
      if (params.keys & ['category_id', 'sub_category', 'manufacturer', 'country', 'state', 'keyword']).present?
        if params[:category_id].present?
          @category = Category.active.find params[:category_id]
        else
          @category = Category.active.find params[:sub_category] if params[:sub_category].present?
        end
        @root_categories = Category.active.roots
        @sub_categories = @category.children.active if params[:category_id].present?
        @sub_categories ||= {}
        @countries = Country.active.all
        @manufacturers = Manufacturer.active.all
        @states = State.active.where("country_id = ?", params[:country]) if params[:country].present?
        @states ||= {} 
        unless params[:category_id].present? && params[:sub_category].present?
          params[:category_id] = @category.id if params[:category_id].present?
          params[:sub_category] = @category.id if params[:sub_category].present?
        end   
        @equipments = Equipment.active.filter(params.slice(:manufacturer, :country, :state, :category_id, :sub_category, :keyword)).order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}, created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per(per_page_items)               
      else
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Something went wrong!"
    end

  end
```

**concerns**

```
module Filterable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def filter(filtering_params)
      results = self.where(nil)
      filtering_params.each do |key, value|
        results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
      end
      results
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: does `https://example.com/search?category_id=construction-and-heavy-equipment` work after implement?

Comment: yes it does @seaify-Freelancer

Comment: can u paster the controller code?

Comment: show the `Equipment.active` method or scope also.

Comment: Actually its a big method. I sliced it. I ll post the whole thing.

Comment: Did you check it @seaify-Freelancer I updated it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142482/discussion-between-seaify-freelancer-and-user3576036).

Comment: I have update the answer, it works at my mac now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `friendly_id` source code, you should use `find_by_friendly_id`. Because the find method first query by slug, then fall back to the regular find method.

```
# If the id is "unfriendly", it will call the original find method.
# If the id is a numeric string like '123' it will first look for a friendly
# id matching '123' and then fall back to looking for a record with the
# numeric id '123'.
#
# Since FriendlyId 5.0, if the id is a numeric string like '123-foo' it
# will *only* search by friendly id and not fall back to the regular find
# method.
#
# If you want to search only by the friendly id, use {#find_by_friendly_id}.
```

Change code

```
@category = Category.active.find params[:category_id]
```

to this

```
@category = Category.active.friendly.find_by_friendly_id params[:category_id]
```

And check https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/648#issuecomment-75172624, it's another solution, but more complex.

Comment: Hey man. I got this solution working and I got the url with `id=number`to fall on 404. But now they want the old url to redirect to the new url. The one with `id=name`. Shall I post it as a new question ?

Comment: suggest post it as new question.

Comment: Posted. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626580/how-to-redirect-old-urls-to-new-friendly-id-generated-urls-in-rails-app

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by two ways:

1. Instead of sending `id` from view you can send `slug`.
2. Other way is to set some `redirect` code inside `controller` if you find numeric `id` in request.